# How can you generate multiple vectors of different length in R?

Tags: r

I would like to use a for loop to generate multiple vectors and save their values for later use. The end result ideally would be:

```
vector_1 = c(1)
vector_2 = c(1,2,3)
vector_3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
.
.
.
vector_i = c(1,2,3,...,n) #for some n generated during the loop. This n does not always have an upper bound.
```

This is so that I can use each vector later on to plot multiple lines on the same graph with the axis of the graph scaled correctly.

The following code is the best example I can come up with to try and describe the idea but obviously using 'vector_i' for each loop is not going to work.

```
for (i in 1:n){
  length = sample(1:i^2,1)
  vector_i = seq(1,length)
}
```

Comment: this is probably a duplicate. You need `assign()` to do exactly what you're specifying, but it generally works better in the flow of things to make your vectors elements of a (named) list instead of creating them as separate named object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following function:

```r
make_vectors <- function(n) lapply(seq(n), function(i) seq(sample(i^2, 1)))
```

Which allows:

```r
vector <- make_vectors(5)

vector
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

And you can access each one like this:

```r
vector[[5]]
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

This keeps your global environment tidy and allows you to iterate through your vectors more easily than writing them all as independent entities.

Comment: Of course, make a list of vectors and call it using `[[n]]`. Thank you this is a much better way to do it and will still allow me to call each one individually for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `sequence`

```
v1 <- sequence(c(1, 3, 6))
v1
#[1] 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

If we need it in a `list`

```
split(v1, cumsum(v1 == 1))
#$`1`
#[1] 1

#$`2`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`3`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```